# Deploy InfoPath form to production that reads from list on development machine

Tags: 2013, workflow, infopath

In InfoPath you can create a new data connection and then you can READ or SUBMIT data to a particular list or library. When you add a new data connection InfoPath asks you full site name such as:

```
http://devserver/sites/companysite
```

My question is when I deploy it to production server, how will I change this URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deployment of this in this case would be to reconfigure all the data connections to point to the production locations, update your publishing settings to point to your production site, saving the form as a new file name, then publishing.

This will leave you with 2 forms, one for Dev, pointed to a dev instance, and a production form, pointed to a production instance.